# ren won't change files with quotations

Tags: cmd.exe

My client sent me files that I am to upload to her website that contain quotation marks in them. I have downloaded so many rename softwares but none of them can replace the quotations. Then I tried to rename via cmd but no luck

I tried:

```
ren Adam-Pally--"Happy-Endings"-.jpg Adam-Pally--Happy-Endings-.jpg
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paul suggests, try the single-character wild card "?" for the quotes. E.G.

**ren Adam-Pally--?Happy-Endings?-.jpg Adam-Pally--Happy-Endings-.jpg**

You can also try the old 8.3 (short) filename:

1. In a Command prompt opened to the folder, enter **dir /x**. You should see both the full filename and the abbreviated form, e.g. **ADAM-P~1.JPG**  and **Adam-Pally--Happy-Endings-.jpg**
2. Use the 8.3 name in the **ren** operation. This won't work, though, if the quotation mark falls within the first six characters (tilde *n* being seventh and eighth).
3. To rename a batch of files to 8.3 format, create a subfolder, **X**, and use *xcopy*, e.g. **xcopy *.* x**/n**

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to escape a quote by using a double quote. Thus ren "Adam-Pally--""Happy-Endings""-.jpg" "Adam-Pally--Happy-Endings-.jpg"

Comment: yeah it says that file is not found